# PHP While loop will not display multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

My script below will only print one row from the sql database. I want to display multiple rows with a first and a last name. This is a friends list. Code is below.

Thank you,
Red.

```
<?php
             $q = "SELECT * FROM `friendslist` WHERE `id1` = '{$_SESSION['id']}' OR `id2` = '{$_SESSION['id']}' AND `confirmed` = '1'";

$res = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die("<h1>4:)Fatal Error! Please contact administration.</h1>".mysql_error());

    while($friends = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    if($_SESSION['id']==$friends['id1']){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM `clientusers` WHERE `id` = '{$friends['id2']}' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $q);
    while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>

        <li class="chat__human">
            <img class="chat__avatar" src="https://robohash.org/joe" alt="" />
            <span class="chat__name"><?php print($list['firstname']);?> &nbsp;<?php print($list['lastname']);?></span>
        </li>

    <?}

    }if($_SESSION['id']==$friends['id2']){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM `clientusers` WHERE `id` = '{$friends['id1']}' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $q);


    while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>

            <li class="chat__human">
            <img class="chat__avatar" src="https://robohash.org/joe" alt="" />
            <span class="chat__name"><?php print($list['firstname']);?>&nbsp;<?php print($list['lastname']);?></span>
        </li>

    <?}
    }
        }



       ?>
```

Comment: The way you collect data from the database seems correct. Can you run that query in phpMyAdmin and see if you get multiple or single result(s)?

Comment: Ok give me a minute to run it in phpMyAdmin. And ill post the results.

Comment: For one, you should group the conditions in the query, you might be getting undesired results if you don't. Use parenthesis to group them, since you have both AND and OR in your condition. Then you should learn how to utilize prepared statements. Also mixing some mysql with mysqli, that's like apples and oranges - very different

Comment: And instead of doing a queries depending on results from another, it looks like you should use JOIN instead

Comment: Go to the line after your first query, `echo $q;` and copy and paste that text into PHPMyAdmin. Comment out the rest of the script if necessary.

Comment: Qirel, I am not sure how I would do that. I have never heard of grouping them with a parenthesis. Could I get an example?

 Also @ÜmitAparı I ran the query in phpMyAdmin and the query displayed multiple rows as it should.

Comment: It looks like you want `WHERE (\`id1\` = '{$_SESSION['id']}' OR \`id2\` = '{$_SESSION['id']}') AND \`confirmed\` = '1'"`, notice the parenthesis which groups the ids

Comment: Ok then, I'd recommend you to use LEFT JOINS in your sql code rather than firing another query while other query hasn't finished fetching the data yet. That's the only propable problem I observe at your code

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that the variable "$res" in the statement below

```
while($friends = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
```

is being overwritten by the statement below

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM `clientusers` WHERE `id` = '{$friends['id2']}' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $res = mysqli_query($db, $q);
```

So when the outer while loop return to fetch the second record its presented with a new result. So try naming the resource variables $res1 and $res2 to avoid confusion.

SO the code would look like

```
$res1 = mysqli_query($db, $q) or die("<h1>4:)Fatal Error! Please contact administration.</h1>".mysql_error());
while($friends = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)){
....
....
....
$res2 = mysqli_query($db, $q);
while($list = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){?>
```